# Laravel keep public folder in sync

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5, vendor

When using `composer` on laravel development, is there a way to keep the folders in sync `<root>/public/` with `<root>/vendor/mymodule/src/public`?

I use `php artisan vendor:publish` to publish my assets to the root, but while developing I have to copy & paste the changes back to my vendor folder to keep them in sync, which is really error prone.

Any best practices will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Best

Comment: I think you should not edit the file inside `vendor` folder

Comment: The vendor Folder Contains my Custom modules. Is there any development approach of how to develop laravel by using a modular approach?

Comment: It appears there may be some related answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/14643852/816584

Comment: Thanks! Seems to fix my issue. I will try this